# Byte32 error, even after converting string to hex

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, addresses, bytes

I looked everywhere for people with similar problems, but I couldn't find anything.

I am confused why I keep getting this error (yes, I know others have had this error too, but not for the same reason as I):

```
>Error: invalid bytes32 value (arg=&quot;_orgName&quot;, coderType=&quot;bytes32&quot;, value=&quot;0x7b22436f6e74656e742d54797065223a226170706c69636174696f6e2f782d7777772d666f726d2d75726c656e636f646564222c224e616d65223a22546573742075736572227d&quot;)
```

1) The information the node server is passing to the contract is a payload from a webpage.

2) Essentially here is what is happening:

- Node takes form payload which is a json object and converts it into hex
- Send hex to the contract with the 3 fields `orgName`,`helloId`,`fctChain`.

I know I am passing in the right data, but I keep getting an error return. When i did a `typeof convertToHex` i got a `string`.

Any guidance is helpful.

Thank you,

Here's what my code looks like:

```
function sendToContract(req, res, next) {

  let convertToHex = web3.utils.toHex(JSON.stringify(req.body));

  ACF.methods.registerNewAsset(convertToHex, convertToHex, fctAddress).send()
    .then(results => {
      res.send(results)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // console.log(err)
    })
  res.send(results);
}
```

Here's what the contract looks like:

```
function registerNewAsset(bytes32 _orgName, uint _hellId, bytes32 _fctChain) external onlyOwner {

        NewAsset storage asset = hercIdToAsset[_hercId];

        asset.orgName = _orgName;
        asset.helloId = _helloId;
        asset.fctChain = _fctChain;

        addressToAssetArray[msg.sender].push(asset);

    }
```

My goal was to implement the send transaction based on this documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

I'm using web3js + node + solidity.

Comment: I suggest that you `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))` and see what exactly it is that you're trying to convert to hex.

Comment: @goodvibration i was converting the entire form payload into hex. turns out i only needed 3 portions of it, so now i am reassigning the variables to specific portion of the payload and converting that into hex and then pushing it out to the smart contract, however, i am not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, there are ample things wrong in code.

```
let convertToHex = web3.utils.toHex(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

In this line, you are trying to convert complete request body in hex not a property of it, which doesn't seem a desired behaviour.

```
function registerNewAsset(bytes32 _orgName, uint _hellId, bytes32 _fctChain)
```

Apart from this, in this line, you second parameter is `uint` but you are sending same hex (i.e. `convertToHex`) for `_helloId`.

Also, from the name of third parameter(i.e. `fctAddress`), it seems that you are passing an address to `bytes32` type variable `_fctChain`.

I think, rectifying each of them will get it working.